# Strange crash issue on iOS 5 and iOS 6

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios6

Can anyone help me decoding below crash log from iPhone Configuration utility of iPhone Device

```
Oct 19 11:09:18 iPhone-AIPV02 kbd[1099] <Warning>: -[TIXPCDataTransport _handleForPurpose:withReplyBlock:] couldn't get data source for purpose=__TIRDTUD
Oct 19 11:09:18 iPhone-AIPV02 mClient[1096] <Warning>: __47+[TIUserDictionaryController loadWordKeyPairs:]_block_invoke_0  Received nil NSData for TIRemoteDataUserDict
Oct 19 11:09:20 iPhone-AIPV02 librariand[1100] <Notice>: MMe quota status changed: under quota
Oct 19 11:09:35 iPhone-AIPV02 lockdownd[29] <Notice>: 2fe93000 spawn_and_handle_checkin: Timeout on socket /var/run/lockdown/checkin.1012 waiting for com.apple.crashreportmover to checkin for Xcode. spawn=1350625160 select=1350625160 now=1350625175
Oct 19 11:09:35 iPhone-AIPV02 ReportCrash[1103] <Error>: libMobileGestalt copySystemVersionDictionaryValue: Could not lookup ReleaseType from system version dictionary
Oct 19 11:09:35 iPhone-AIPV02 ReportCrash[1103] <Error>: libMobileGestalt copySystemVersionDictionaryValue: Could not lookup ReleaseType from system version dictionary
Oct 19 11:09:35 iPhone-AIPV02 ReportCrash[1103] <Warning>: Not internal build
Oct 19 11:09:35 iPhone-AIPV02 ReportCrash[1103] <Error>: libMobileGestalt copySystemVersionDictionaryValue: Could not lookup ReleaseType from system version dictionary
Oct 19 11:09:35 iPhone-AIPV02 ReportCrash[1103] <Notice>: Saved crashreport to /Library/Logs/CrashReporter/stacks-2012-10-19-110935.plist using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 0 egid: 0
Oct 19 11:09:35 iPhone-AIPV02 ReportCrash[1103] <Error>: libMobileGestalt copySystemVersionDictionaryValue: Could not lookup ReleaseType from system version dictionary
Oct 19 11:09:39 iPhone-AIPV02 com.apple.debugserver-189[1095] <Warning>: 1 +0.000000 sec [0447/0303]: error: ::ptrace (request = PT_THUPDATE, pid = 0x0448, tid = 0x2503, signal = 0) err = Resource busy (0x00000010)
Oct 19 11:09:39 iPhone-AIPV02 com.apple.debugserver-189[1095] <Warning>: 2 +0.033249 sec [0447/0303]: error: ::task_threads ( task = 0x1603, thread_list => 0x0, thread_list_count => 0 ) err = (os/kern) invalid argument (0x00000004)
Oct 19 11:09:39 iPhone-AIPV02 com.apple.debugserver-189[1095] <Warning>: 3 +0.000988 sec [0447/0303]: error: ::task_info ( target_task = 0x1603, flavor = TASK_BASIC_INFO, task_info_out => 0x2fdbee6c, task_info_outCnt => 8 ) err = (os/kern) invalid argument (0x00000004)
Oct 19 11:09:39 iPhone-AIPV02 com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.csam.app.mClient[0x2ae5][1096]) <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.csam.app.mClient[0x2ae5]) Exited: Killed: 9
Oct 19 11:09:39 iPhone-AIPV02 com.apple.debugserver-189[1095] <Warning>: 4 +0.025519 sec [0447/1303]: error: ::read ( 5, 0x2ff22a0c, 1024 ) => -1 err = Bad file descriptor (0x00000009)
O
```

on my Xcode console I can only see below log and then **My iPhone Device gets Restart**

```
2012-10-19 11:09:18.234 mClient[1096:907] __47+[TIUserDictionaryController loadWordKeyPairs:]_block_invoke_0  Received nil NSData for TIRemoteDataUserDict
```

Apart from this if I see my Crash log on Device then I am getting very strange Logs as below It shows me Unknown app name in Organizer..

```
Incident Identifier: C0A41418-FFB1-480F-9407-3DCABDF8C817
CrashReporter Key:   424c30662723fd3ef8386fa097c54696af46b054
Hardware Model:      iPhone3,3
OS Version:          iPhone OS 6.0 (10A403)
Kernel Version:      Darwin Kernel Version 13.0.0: Sun Aug 19 00:27:34 PDT 2012; root:xnu-2107.2.33~4/RELEASE_ARM_S5L8930X
Date:                2012-10-19 11:07:25 +0530
Time since snapshot: 348 ms

Free pages:        945
Active pages:      7743
Inactive pages:    3807
Throttled pages:   19087
Purgeable pages:   9
Wired pages:       96860
Largest process:   mClient

Processes
     Name                    <UUID>                       rpages       recent_max       [reason]          (state)

           timed <f3f0e010a9a13ae69b5761a5db3f4a3c>          231              231         [vm]         (daemon) (idle)
       accountsd <ac0fce15c1a2350d951efc498d521ac7>          240              240         [vm]         (daemon) (idle)
            afcd <b0aff2e7952e34a9882fec81a8dcdbb2>          117              117         [vm]         (daemon) (idle)
networkd_privile <f8858e6f66af39ab8ce8f105cfa6872f>           94               94         [vm]         (daemon) (idle)
        installd <309cd72e8af43ad1b77d96274d0b0ff7>          310              310         [vm]         (daemon) (idle)
             lsd <6a9f5b5f36b23fc78f87b6d8f1f49a9d>          270              270         [vm]         (daemon) (idle)
     MobilePhone <3fca241f2a193d0fb8264218d296ea41>         1771             1771         [vm]         (resume) (continuous)
      librariand <c9a9be81aa9632f0a913ce79b911f27e>          199              199         [vm]         (daemon)
            tccd <eb5ddcf533663f8d987d67cae6a4c4ea>          124              124         [vm]         (daemon)
             kbd <3e7136ddcefc3d77a01499db593466cd>          545              545         [vm]         (daemon)
         mClient <2a2692e6564f30e1b683883adb7cb323>        97400            98186         [vm]         (frontmost) (resume)
            ptpd <04a56fce67053c57a7979aeea8e5a7ea>          837              837         [vm]         (daemon)
 assistivetouchd <1f4670e8371f3afbaaee4898c459e148>         1141             1141         [vm]         (daemon)
         syslogd <cbef142fa0a839f0885afb693fb169c3>          117              170         [vm]         (daemon)
           wifid <9472b090746237998cdbb9b34f090d0c>          366              366         [vm]         (daemon)
       locationd <892cd1c9ffa43c99a82dba197be5f09e>         1199             1199         [vm]         (daemon)
    mediaserverd <80657170daca32c9b8f3a6b1faac43a2>          463              463         [vm]         (daemon)
   iaptransportd <f784f30dc09d32078d87b450e8113ef6>          234              234                      (daemon)
     SpringBoard <27372aae101f3bbc87804edc10314af3>         3371             3371                     
      backboardd <5037235f295b33eda98eb5c72c098858>         3131             3131                      (daemon)
  UserEventAgent <6edfd8d8dba23187b05772dcdfc94f90>          404              404                      (daemon)
            geod <73e79779d11a312cb70c3770e494ceab>          266              266                      (daemon)
springboardservi <ff6f64b3a21a39c9a1793321eefa5304>            0                0                      (daemon)
       distnoted <a89af76ec8633ac2bbe99bc2b7964bb0>          101              101                      (daemon)
notification_pro <845b7beebc8538ca9ceef731031983b7>          118              118                      (daemon)
filecoordination <fbab576f37a63b56a1039153fc1aa7d8>          127              127                      (daemon)
            apsd <94d8051dd5f5362f82d775bc279ae608>          337              337                      (daemon)
        networkd <0032f46009f53a6c80973fe153d1a588>          157              157                      (daemon)
      aggregated <8c3c991dc4153bc38aee1e841864d088>           87               87                      (daemon)
     debugserver <185719f06f1631d4922c652bdd4c8529>            0                0                      (daemon)
          powerd <2d2ffed5e69638aeba1b92ef124ed861>          132              132                      (daemon)
             ubd <74dc476d1785300e9fcda555fcb8d774>          336              336                      (daemon)
   mDNSResponder <3e557693f3073697a58da6d27a827d97>          280              280                      (daemon)
       lockdownd <ba1358c7a8003f1b91af7d5f58dd5bbe>          192              192                      (daemon)
        BTServer <c92fbd7488e63be99ec9dbd05824f5e5>          407              407                      (daemon)
         configd <4245d73a9e96360399452cf6b8671844>          396              396                      (daemon)
   fairplayd.N92 <db9f16dba3f8358e9b49b446eea2f186>          137              137                      (daemon)
       fseventsd <996cc4ca03793184aea8d781b55bce08>          288              288                      (daemon)
         imagent <1e68080947be352590ce96b7a1d07b2f>          298              298                      (daemon)
         lockbot <4ab4aa38f8b530c984dd4840506f8b08>          228              418                      (daemon)
   syncdefaultsd <991361b1e471398499afeeb750d132f1>          221              221                      (daemon)
      CommCenter <1f425e1e897d32e8864fdd8eeaa803a8>          616              616                      (daemon)
         notifyd <51c0e03da8a93ac8a595442fcaac531f>          149              149                      (daemon)

**End**
```

Comment: is there any class named `TIUserDictionaryController` in ur code.. if yes, search for concerned string `loadWordKeyPairs`,`TIRemoteDataUserDict` in that classes..

Comment: NO there is no such class in my Code. It is Apple's class.

Comment: does it happens only while running your app? and does it happens in both simulator & device?

Comment: definitely it happens while running app. Also when i Keep Simulate Memory warning on Simulator then this error comes on Simulator also. Device has also same error.

Comment: `TIUserDictionaryController` this class refers to TextInput framework.. can u check what operations u r performing related to text inputs for `UITextField` or `UITextView`.. and also what changes u r making when memory warning occurs.?

Comment: I check all that part but this issues comes before my code reach to that code... While debugging i found that this error comes before my textview is drawn on screen... also this error comes on Separate thread then main thread so not able to reproduce everytime...

Comment: I am having this exact same crash with the exact same strange crash report, have you figured anything out?  When I look at the console for my device, it seems like it kills many apps at the same time, and does seem to be related to memory, although I never see any memory warnings prior to the crash.

Comment: Actually, yes i resolved this issue... but truly saying I don't know why it was crashing. But i had changed some of the code in my MapView and and this gets resolved...

Comment: did u tried to remove the delegation of the objects, when you recieve the memory ?

Comment: Probably yes but dont remembered because i change much more code on try and error basis... and hence i dont know what could be the issue..

Comment: try to set an exception breakpoint, this will show you the code throwing this exception

Comment: I had done this at time of crash and found that It was crashing during Map load but no crash log found pointing to my code... you can see my crash logs...

Answer (score 3):

Restart your phone. I had these errors occurring and things like the camera app would crash, they started occurring when my device ran out of space, I deleted a bunch of files but the errors stayed... I restarted my phone and all worked well, I thought to do this because when I would test the app on other devices it worked fine and these errors didn't occur.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem with the same `[TIUserDictionaryController loadWordKeyPairs:]...` error. I noticed I had one of my `UITextFields`'s delegate set to `File's owner` but wasn't using the delegate. I removed the textField's delegate (from my storyboard file), and all worked well :)

It was weird though, cause everything was working fine for days with testing, I submitted the app for review, and 3 days later I tried to show someone the app, and it kept crashing out of nowhere. Perhaps it's some strange bug in Apple's `UITextField` class